# After splitting a line into 3 equal parts, the resulting parts are non-continuous

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I have lines that I want to split into 3 equal parts, in order to check that my sampling points are in the last third of the line.

I used the editor and the split function as shown in the photo 1, the resulting parts are irregularly divided photo 2,3 and 4 (the three resulting parts)

How can I make the divisions continuous and not irregular?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You seem to be starting with a discontinuous multipart linestring. Split doesn't have much meaning in that context. You need to sequence the parts into a single-part geometry first.

Comment: Use Multipart to Single part tool to explode your lines into single parts. Snap ends of line bits and merge them in editing session to create single part out of relevant bits.