# After splitting a line into 3 equal parts, the resulting parts are non-continuous. Part 2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, splitting

Before I have asked here about how to divide a polyline into 3 equal parts, since when I do it it is divided into three parts of the same size but not continuously. Vince has answered me (*"You seem to be starting with a discontinuous multipart linestring. Split doesn't have much meaning in that context. You need to sequence the parts into a single-part geometry first".*) but I didn't understand much your answer, I'm a bit of a newbie in GIS, sorry.

Maybe I have explained myself wrong, I will explain it again with more images to make it clearer. In the answers to the original post it didn't let me write much, that's why I put it here

My shp is a layer of different rivers (each with a color, see photo 1), and I want to divide each river into 3 equal segments to see if my sampling points are located in the last third of the river.

[image: photo 1, my shp]

In the attribute table of that shp, each river is represented by a polyline (photo 2). [image: attribute table] I understand that you said me that each polyline is a multipart linestring, right? I have tried to transform them into a single part as you have recommended, but when doing this what used to be a single polyline (represented a river, which interests me), now they become many simple lines (so it does not make sense, I I want to divide the original line into 3 equal parts to see the last third)

Focusing on a specific river, I use the editor, select the polyline corresponding to the specific river and try to divide it into 3 equal and continuous parts. And indeed, the line is divided into 3 parts of the same size but not continuous (I attach the photos of the previous post)

[image: process of splitting]
[image: one of resultants parts]
[image: two of resultants parts]
[image: three of resultants parts]

Vince answered my question saying *"You seem to be starting with a discontinuous multipart linestring. Split doesn't have much meaning in that context. You need to sequence the parts into a single-part geometry first".* I tried to transform this polyline in single-part using "Multipart to singlepart" tool but when I did it, the river (polyline) is transformed into several segments, and the attribute table shows more than 1 polyline for each river. So it doesn't make sense to apply the split in 3 equal parts there, since I want it over the total.

Surely it is a theory error, I am practically new to this.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again, rather edit existing question with the new info: [After splitting a line into 3 equal parts, the resulting parts are non-continuous](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422507/after-splitting-a-line-into-3-equal-parts-the-resulting-parts-are-non-continuou)

Comment: That post is my question that I asked a couple of hours ago, but Vince's answer is not very clear to me, that's why I have put it back with more images and more detail (comments to the post are limited in terms of the number of words )

Comment: Just [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/422507/edit) the original question and add new info.

Comment: Oh!! Thanks. Today is my first day here and I didn´t  know about it!! Thanks and sorry!!